# Scenario where Flow works for destructured function argument, but not for non-destructured argument

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have this code:

```
function myFunction({x}: {x?: number} = {}) {
    console.log(x);
    return 'foo';
}

function wrapper({x}: {x: number}) {
    return myFunction({x});
}

function myFunction2({x}: {x?: number} = {}) {
    console.log(x);
    return 'foo';
}

function wrapper2(args: {x: number}) {
    return myFunction2(args);
}
```

`myFunction` and `wrapper` do exactly the same thing as `myFunction2` and `wrapper2`, right? But Flow thinks there is an error in the latter copy [(live demo)](https://flowtype.org/try/#0GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DFzXmAFAbwA8BfALkSIH5ywRkAjAUwCdjEBeC4gSgoChEiCAgDOcADaMAdOLgBzXIW4BuAYmaMoIZkgDkwOHF2rifPqEiwEiAO7MAhgAdHLAiXJEadJq1741Glo6KBhYVnhEPCZmFtjWaJiWOABMbmQUhNSItAwsbJz4PPyCwmBikjLyiioBmtp6BkbR5mE4tg7OLKn2zHIiHoReub7F6nXBCa0I3b0iNcRAA):

```
16:   return myFunction2(args);
                         ^ object type. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of
10: function myFunction2({x}: {x?: number} = {}) {
                              ^ object type
```

Is this a bug, or am I missing something and the two examples are not equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a smaller example that illustrates the same issue:

```
function myFunction({x}: {x?: number} = {}) {
  console.log(x);
  return 'foo';
}

const x: number = 5;
const obj: {x: number} = {x};

myFunction({x});
myFunction(obj);
```

([tryflow](https://flowtype.org/try/#0GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DFzXmAFAbwA8BfALkSIH5ywRkAjAUwCdjEBeC4gSgoChEiCAgDOcADaMAdOLgBzXIW4BuAYmaMoIZkgDkwOHF2rifPsLAioiQjTpNmHRAFZVFq4jj0AVuSJ2GFjZOImJVPjRMSFgEAhIVCIwsGLwvbxUgA))

On the second function call, Flow issues this error:

```
10: myFunction(obj);
               ^ object type. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of
1: function myFunction({x}: {x?: number} = {}) {
                            ^ object type
```

The reason this happens has nothing to do with destructuring. It's simply because objects are mutable, so subtyping rules don't always apply like you would expect if they were immutable.

When typechecking a the calls to `myFunction`, Flow looks only at the type signature, not at the implementation. So, as far as Flow knows, `myFunction` could take the mutable object which it is passed, and set its `x` property to `null`. If the caller believes that the `x` property must never be `null`, this would violate its assumptions.

In the first function call, we construct a brand new object, so Flow can safely infer that is has the type `{x?: number}`, since it knows that nobody else is holding a reference to it.